# Detect number of keys being pushed Unity C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to make a grid-based movement system, and I have a bug where the player will move an odd amount when multiple inputs come in. Is there a way to detect how many keys on the keyboard are being pushed?

For example, something like:

```
If(numberOfKeysDown > 1)
```

or something?

I know you can do touch counts if working with mobile, but I'm not sure about keys. Thanks for your time!

Comment: While this has given me some new info on Events, it sounds like your asking for help on a workaround rather than the *actual* problem of bad movement.  Perhaps we could help you with that, too? (in another question).

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to actually test what you said it should be enough to check for [`Input.anyKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-anyKey.html)

> Is any key or mouse button currently held down

```
if(Input.anyKey)
```

---

If you want to check specific keys you could use [`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) and [Linq `Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count) like e.g.

```
// Fancy queries ;)
using System.Linq;

...

// The keycodes you wan to check
private HashSet<KeyCode> keysToCheck = { KeyCode.W, KeyCode.A, KeyCode.S, KeyCode.D };

int numberOfKeysPressed;

private void Update ()
{
    numberOfKeysPressed = keysToCheck.Count(key => Input.GetKey(key));
    // This basically equals doing 
    // var numberOfKeysPressed = 0;
    // foreach(var key in KeyToCheck)
    //{
    //    if(Input.GetKey(key)) numberOfKeysPressed++;
    //}
}
```

Or you could use [`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) and [`Input.GetKeyUp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html) and do something like

```
private HashSet<KeyCode> keysToCheck = { KeyCode.W, KeyCode.A, KeyCode.S, KeyCode.D };

int numberOfKeysPressed;

private void Update ()
{
    foreach (var key in KeyToCheck)
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(key)) numberOfKeysPressed++;

        if(Input.GetKeyUp(key)) numberOfKeysPressed--;
    }
}
```

If you want all [`KeyCode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html) values you could use

```
private void Awake ()
{
    keysToCheck = new HashSet<KeyCode>((KeyCode[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)));
}
```

---

If you really want to get the amount of **any** key presses on the keyboard it would probably be more efficient to directly use [`Event.current`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event-current.html) and do something like

```
HashSet<string> currentlyPressedKeys = new HashSet<string>();

void OnGUI () 
{
    Event e = Event.current;
    switch(e.type)
    {
        case EventType.KeyDown:
            var key = e.keyCode.ToString();
            if(!currentlyPressedKeys.Contains(key)) currentlypressedKeys.Add(key);
            break;

        case EventType.KeyUp:
            var key = e.keyCode.ToString();
            if(currentlyPressedKeys.Contains(key)) currentlypressedKeys.Remove(key);
            break;
    }
}
```

Now wherever you need to know you can do e.g

```
if(currentlyPressedKeys.Count > XY)
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think theres is a specific method for this.

You could however write your own counter method using `Input.GetKeyDown`.

Like so

```
int GetKeysDownCount() {
    var keysDown = 0;
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)
        keysDown++;
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)
        keysDown++;
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)
        keysDown++;
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)
        keysDown++;
    return keysDown;
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

Comment: What if there are more keys ona keyboard than only WASD? ^^

Comment: Well played, your solution is far superior to mine XD